# addEditor and removeEditor on certain conditions for google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I learned from [this question] ([Automatic Lock/Protect Rows/cells in Google Sheets at a specific time in other Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996499/automatic-lock-protect-rows-cells-in-google-sheets-at-a-specific-time-in-other-c)) on how to lock certain cells with certain conditions and Jess's answer works perfectly fine.

I am just wondering if I could add more codes to unlock the cells at a certain conditions as well. e.g: if users do thing1, lock the cell B1, if users do thing2, unlock the cell B1 for future editing.

Here the code I revised based on Jess's answer, the blocking (removeEditor) works fine, but the "else if" condition I added to unblock the cell did not work, and the cells are NOT unblocked under the condition.

```
function onEdit(e) { 

 var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet1=ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");  

 var active = sheet1.getActiveCell();

 var nextnum = sheet1.getRange(active.getRow(),8).getValue();

 var shouldbeblocking= sheet1.getRange(active.getRow()-1,7)

 var them = Session.getActiveUser();

 var theiremails = them.getEmail();


// to unlock the cell, NOT WORKING

   if (nextnum == 22) {
 
 shouldbeblocking.protect().addEditor(theiremails);
 
 shouldbeblocking.setNote("unLocked") ;
  }

 // to lock the cell (codes working fine)

  else if (nextnum == 1) {

 shouldbeblocking.protect().removeEditor("xxx@xxx.com") ;
 shouldbeblocking.setNote("Locked") ;
  }



}
```

---

As per @ross's suggestion, I added `Logger.log` onto my code (within the if statement), and below is the screenshot of the execution transcript, it seems like the code runs through the if statement, and oddly the "unlocked" `setNote` works cuz I can see the "unlocked" note on the cell, but that cell is still blocked:

[image: execution log screenshot]

Comment: Nick, are you sure that 1) `nextnum` ever reaches the `22` value; 2) `getActiveUser().getEmail()` result is the same as the email in `removeEditor()`?

Comment: Hey Oleg, thanks for the reply!  [1] yes!  on google sheet i set up some if statement to change the value of nextnum to 22.  [2] yes!  currently i am only sharing my google sheet to one other person's gmail account. and the getActiveUser's email is the same as the xxx@xxx.com I used for removeEditor.    With all these, do you think my code has logical issues? thanks !!

Comment: Add a `Logger.log` inside your `if` statement that you think working to make sure that it is actually getting into that part of the code. Also could you show your execution transcript (go to `view > execution transcript`) to view this then add the contents to the question.

Comment: Nick, I expected at least one of the answers to be "no") Please, do what @ross said to make sure that the script execution actually reaches the the `if` statement (btw, about [2] - are sure or you called something like `theiremails==='xxx@xxx.com'` and it returned `true`?)

Comment: @ross, Hey Ross, thanks for the help! I added the logger.log + execution transcript onto the content, it seems like the code gets to the if statement, and I did notice the "setNote" of "unlocked" appears on the cell, oddly the code runs the setNote part in the if statement, but not on the other addEditor,

Comment: @OlegValter, Hey Oleg, I added the execution transcript onto my post, and it seems like the code runs the "setNote" part (and I did see the unblocked note on the cell), but that cell is still blocked.....   and sorry for the confusion, that xxx@xxx.com thingy is just nameless, in my actual code, i was using the actual email address and I double checked the accuracy of the email address. thanks!

Comment: Nick, no confusion, I understand that xxx@xxx.com is a dummy email, just wanted to know whether you actually get the email via `getEmail()` call, as there are a bunch of scenarios where `onEdit()` trigger [can't access user's email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()). It's obvious from your transcript, that this is not the case. What's more, `addEditor()` also fires correctly

Comment: And I think I now get what's wrong - take a look at [`protect()` method documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) - each time you run your function, a new layer of protection is added, that's the only explanation (I will get in detail in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum up - there is an easily overlooked note in the `protect()` method documentation that "**If the range is already protected, this method creates a new protected range that overlaps the existing one**", which means that each time your `onEdit(e)` trigger fires, at least one new protection layer is created instead of being overridden.

You should instead access `Protection` instances created for the `Spreadsheet` via `getProtections()` method and call the `addEditor()` and `removeEditor()` methods on an element from the resulting `Array` (to be able to distinguish between `Protection` instances, make use of `getRange()` and `getEditors()` methods (at least `Logger.log()` or `console.log()` them to keep track).

You will probably want to check if the user can edit the protected `Range` before the add/remove procedure – in this case, use the `canEdit()` method on an aquired `Protection`.

**Useful links**

1. `canEdit(e)` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#canEdit());
2. `remove()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove());
3. `getProtections()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getProtections(ProtectionType)) (protections must be filtered by [type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection-type));

Comment: Hey Oleg, great thanks! since I am fairly new on app script,  I am still searching on how to use getProtections to find the protection and change it according to my conditions, once i figure it out, i will come back and select your answer! appreciate it!

Comment: Nick, great! I am yet to update the answer with a bit more detail and documentation reference :) This change should solve the issue you have (make sure you remove all protections from the sheet beforehand, as there might be quite a bunch of them)